# Oracle Enterprise Manager font problem, some text is displayed in Chinese and with squares

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, enterprise-manager

In Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g database control in the following section:

> Setup->Monitoring Templates->"Choose template name and click Edit
>   button"->Policies tab

Texts are displayed in Chinese language and squares.

Like this:

> 䅵摩琠䙩汥⁄敳瑩湡瑩潮
>
> 䝲慮瑩湧⁓䕌䕃吠䅎夠呁䉌䔠偲楶楬敧
>
> 䑩獫**⁇**牯異⁃潮瑡楮猠䑩獫猠潦⁓楧湩晩捡湴汹⁄楦晥牥湴⁓楺敳

How to solve? I want these words to see in English. Please help.

> I found now that some words contains question marks

Thank you.

Comment: was it always like this or is this a new install?

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Enterprise Manager Grid Control Advanced Installation and Configuration Guide 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/install.111/e16847/preparing_for_install.htm#BACIFAIF) has the following section:

> **How can you change the language used in Enterprise Manager Grid Console?**
>
> By default, the Enterprise Manager Grid Control Installation Wizard
>   installs Enterprise Manager Grid Control console with English
>   language. If you want to view them in another language, then select
>   the required languages in the Select Languages screen of the
>   installation wizard.
>
> > **Note:** The language you select here changes the language used in the
> >     Enterprise Manager Grid Control console screens only; it does NOT
> >     change the language used in the installation wizard screens. The
> >     language of the installation wizard screens is based on the operating
> >     system language.
>
> When you select additional languages to install, the installation
>   wizard also installs fonts required to display the languages.
>
> For some components, languages are installed only if you select them
>   during installation. In this case, if you access the application in a
>   language that is not available, it reverts to the locale language.
>
> For other components, available languages are installed regardless of
>   what you select during installation. In this case, however, fonts are
>   installed only for the languages that are explicitly selected. When
>   you access the application, it uses text in your language because the
>   language was installed. However, if you do not have the appropriate
>   fonts to render the text, the text appears as square boxes. This
>   usually applies to the Chinese, Japanese, and Korean languages.

Comment: thank you for you response, but I think I have the different situation: all other tabs are in English just Policies tab is in Chinese. If there was chosen Chinese during the installation then the whole OEM would have been in Chinese, right? But in my case just one section is in Chinese and others are in English.

Comment: Seems logical.  Have you opened a Service Request with Oracle?